# Add Actions & Recommendations to FSC Standard Objects

Tags: financial-services-cloud, actions-and-recommendations

When I attempt to add the `Actions and Recommendations` component to an `InsurancePolicy` Lightning record-page I get the component but there is an error: "Not Available: This page does not support the Actions & Recommendations Component".

When I go to [create "Actions & Recommendations Deployment"](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=console_lex_guided_action_list_component.htm&type=5) I am unable to select the `InsurancePolicy` object, while it's not [explicitly listed as a non-supported object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.224.0.salesforce_guided_engagement.meta/salesforce_guided_engagement/guided_engagement_support.htm).

I'm curious if anyone has any familiarity with it?

Answer (score 0):

Support has confirmed:

> After speaking with product team we have concluded Insurance team
>   never wrote those entities to be supported and/or the Service Process
>   team hasn't added them to be exposed to that feature. I will work on
>   documentation for you however, this is not a feature you can use on
>   this object.

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000Lv4PQAS